# If $E/F$ is a field extension of degree $2$ and $\text{char}(F)\ne 2$ then $E=F(\sqrt a)$ for some $a\in E$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

> Let $E/F$ be a field extension of degree $2$ and $\text{char}(F)\ne 2$.
>
> 1. Show that $E=F(\sqrt a)$ for some $a\in F$.
> 2. Given some $0\ne a,b\in F$, under what conditions $F(\sqrt a)=F(\sqrt b)$?

**My attempt:**

We know that if $E/F$ is a field extension of a prime degree then $E/F$ is simple. Thus we have $E=F(a)$ for some $a\in E$.
Let $f=\text{irr}(a,F)$.

Comment: Grab $a\in E-F$ what can you say about $a^2$?

Comment: For the first point; do you mean *"...for some $a\in F$."* instead? Both are true, but one is more useful than the other.

Comment: @Servaes Corrected it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first part; let $x\in E$ with $x\notin F$. Then $1$, $x$ and $x^2$ are linearly dependent over $F$ because $1,x,x^2\in E$ and $\dim_FE=2$. This means there exist $a,b,c\in F$ such that
$$ax^2+bx+c=0.$$
Of course $a\neq0$ because $x\notin F$ and so we get
$$x^2+\tfrac bax+\tfrac ca=0.$$
Because $\operatorname{char}F\neq2$ we also have $y:=x+\tfrac{b}{2a}\in E$ and this element satisfies
$$y^2+\tfrac{c}{a}-\tfrac{b^2}{4a^2}=0,$$
meaning that $y=\sqrt{\tfrac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}}$, and so we have $E=F(\sqrt{\alpha})$ for $\alpha:=\tfrac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}$.

For the second part; note that $F(\sqrt{\alpha})=F(\sqrt{\beta})$ for nonzero $\alpha,\beta\in F$ if and only if there exist $a,b\in F$ such that $\sqrt{\beta}=a+b\sqrt{\alpha}$. In this case 
$$\beta=(a+b\sqrt{\alpha})^2=a^2+\alpha b^2+2ab\sqrt{\alpha},$$
where $\beta\in F$, and so $ab=0$ because $\operatorname{char}F\neq2$. If $b=0$ then $\sqrt{\beta}=a\in F$ and so $$F(\sqrt{\alpha})=F(\sqrt{\beta})=F(a)=F,$$
meaning that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are both squares in $F$. If $a=0$ then $\sqrt{\beta}=b\sqrt{\alpha}$ and hence $\beta=b^2\alpha$. In both cases we see that $\tfrac{\alpha}{\beta}\in F$ is a square.

Conversely, if $\tfrac{\alpha}{\beta}\in F$ is a square, say $\tfrac{\alpha}{\beta}=c^2$, then $\sqrt{\alpha}=c\sqrt{\beta}$ and so
$$F(\sqrt{\alpha})=F(c\sqrt{\beta})=F(\sqrt{\beta}),$$
which shows that $F(\sqrt{\alpha})=F(\sqrt{\beta})$ if and only if $\tfrac{\alpha}{\beta}$ is a square in $F$.

Comment: I would like to clarify the equality $E=F(\sqrt\alpha)$: We know that $ax^2+bx+c=0$, therefore we know that $x_{1,2}=\frac{-b}{2a}\pm\sqrt\alpha$ thus $x\in F(\sqrt(\alpha)$, and on the same way, $\sqrt\alpha=x-b/2a$ thus $\sqrt\alpha\in F(x)$. Thus $E=F(x)=F(\sqrt\alpha)$.

Comment: Yes; I just gave a few details to verify that indeed the quadratic formula holds over $F$.